# Distributing independant iterations in a subroutine over multiple machines

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, distributed-computing

I have an application that's written in Fortran and there is one particular subroutine call that takes a long time to execute. I was wondering if it's possible to distribute the tasks for computation over multiple nodes.
The current serial flow of the code is as follows:

```
D = Some computations that give me D and it is in memory
subroutine call

<within the subroutine>

iteration from 1 .. n
{

  independent operations on D
}
```

I wish to distribute the iterations over n/4 machines. Can someone please guide me with this? Do let me know if something's not very clear!

Comment: I would take a look into the [*Message Passing Interface (MPI)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) for a distributed memory setup. The Book [*Introduction to High Performance Computing for Scientists and Engineers*](http://amzn.com/143981192X) by Georg Hager is very good as an introduction...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I was taking a look into it but isnt this a single node parallelization? Or can this also be extended to multiple computers for computation?

Comment: "for a distributed memory setup"

Comment: For a single node you are perhaps thinking of OpenMP (OpenMPI may be confusing you).

Comment: Distributed memory will be a lot more work than single node, are you sure (consider Amdahl and the distribution of `D`) that it will be the best you of _your_ time (against the _computer's_)?

Comment: Okay, I get it. Convinced that there is more that i can do over a single node before getting it distributed. So I should be using openMP? Any good place to start this?

Comment: OpenMP works well for many problems.  The ability to switch between sequential and parallel compilation assists in debugging.  I recommend the book "Using OpenMP" by Chapman, Jost and van der Pas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one has existing code and wants to parallelize incrementally (or just one routine), shared memory approaches are the "quick hit".  Especially when it is known that the iterations are independant I'd first recommend looking at compiler flags for auto-parallelization, language constructs such as `DO CONCURRENT` (thanks to @IanH for reminding me of that), and OpenMP compiler directives.

As my extended comment is about distributed memory, however, I'll come to that.

I'll assume you don't have access to some advanced process-spawning setup on all of your potential machines.  That is, you'll have processes running on various machines each being charged for the time regardless of what work is being done.  Then, the work-flow looks like

- Serial outer loop

  - Calculate `D`
  - Distribute `D` to the parallel environment

    - Inner parallel loop on subsets of `D`
  - Gather `D` on the master

If the processors/processes in the parallel environment are doing nothing else - or you're being charged regardless - then this is the same to you as

- Outer loop

  - All processes calculate `D`
  - Each process works on its subset of `D`
  - Synchronize `D`

The communication side, MPI or coarrays (which I'd recommend in this case, again see @IanH's answer, where image synchronization etc., is as limited as a few loops with `[..]`) here is just in the synchronization.

As an endnote: multi-machine coarray support is very limited.  `ifort` as I understand requires an licence beyond the basic, `g95` has some support, the Cray compiler may well.  That's a separate question, however.  MPI would be well supported.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the underlying implementation, coarrays (F2008) may allow processing to be distributed over multiple nodes.  Partitioning the iteration space across the images is relatively straightforward, communication of the results back to one image (or to all images) is where some complexity might arise.  Some introductory material on coarrays can be found [here](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1801-N1850/N1824.pdf).

Again, depending on the underlying implementation, DO CONCURRENT (F2008) may allow parallel processing of iterations (though unlikely to be across nodes).  Restrictions exist on what can be done in the scope of a DO CONCURRENT construct that mean that iterations can be executed in any order, appropriately capable compilers may be able to then transform that further into concurrent execution.